# How can i traverse a complex multi level json string to create objects in Angularjs or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a Json string like this:

```
 var json =     "[{"Id":"1234",
        "FirstName":"One",    
        "Index":"32",
        "Type":"t1",
        "Children":[{"Id":"976","FirstName":"Two","Index":"32","Type":"t2",     

           "Children":[{"Id":"428",
               "FirstName":"Three",            
               "Index":"32",
               "Type":"t3",
               "Children":[],
               "ParentId":"f235"}],        
               
        "ParentId":"f826"}],
     "ParentId":"0000"}]"
```

I want to create a number of objects with only the fields Id,FirstName,Children, not
Index and Type.
Each Object has a number of child Services as well.

So obj1 will have properties Firstname, ParentId and Children and if you drill down
to its Children it will have another object
with Id , firstname , ParentId ,
and for this if we drill down there are no more Children

```
I began by doing something like 
    
    var servicejson = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
     for (let i = 0; i < servicejson).length; i++) {
            var parentnode = {
                Id: servicejson[i].Id,
                FirstName: servicejson[i].JsonValue,        
                ParentId: servicejson[i].ParentId,             
            };        
            
            //check if children
            if (servicejson[i].Children.length > 0) {
                //do something here ??
            }
    }
```

There will be one Object and within that will be a Child , and withing that Child there
is another Child node. I got stuck assigning these to the Object or pushing onto an array
on the Object as I assume it may need a recursive call to assign the Children array and
this is where i need some help
Any ideas on how I can to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

```js
 var json =     [{"Id":"1234",
        "FirstName":"One",    
        "Index":"32",
        "Type":"t1",
        "Children":[{"Id":"976","FirstName":"Two","Index":"32","Type":"t2",     

           "Children":[{"Id":"428",
               "FirstName":"Three",            
               "Index":"32",
               "Type":"t3",
               "Children":[],
               "ParentId":"f235"}],        
               
        "ParentId":"f826"}],
     "ParentId":"0000"}]


const transform = ({Id, FirstName, Children}) => ({
  Id,
  FirstName,
  Children: Children.map(transform)
})

const result = json.map(transform)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Would it work if there was an object that had lets say any number of levels of Children ?

Comment: @Georgia yes because it uses recursion

Comment: thanks so much works fantastically.  One more thing , is it easy to extract each object associatig what its parent is ?

Comment: actually , would i be able to use the transform above t extract all  the firstname in an array  even if in children . So ["One", "Two", "Three"]